# Viewing a .txt file currently being updated in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running a program that is attempting to solve a non-linear equation. It's a black box situation, so I won't go into the details. I basically feed the program some values, and it spits out 5 numbers, the latter of which I compare to a set of criteria that they need to match up with to a certain tolerance. I feed it new values continuously in a search for the input values that give me the 5 numbers that match the criteria.

So, long story short, I'm constantly producing 5 numbers that I am hoping are converging to my criteria. I am currently outputting each iteration's 5 numbers in A,B,C,D,E format and writing to an output txt file. However, until the program completes (if it ever does!), I can't see how A,B,C,D, or E are converging because my txt file is blank until I .close() it. Is there any way that I could see how these values are changing over time in another way? If my 5 numbers are just going all over the place and not converging to anything, I need to consider a different methodology.

Comment: use a good IDE so you can use breakpoints for debugging

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1 - `flush` the buffer after writing each line:

```
from time import sleep

f = open('testfile.txt', 'w')
while True:
    f.write("A, B, C, D, E\n")
    f.flush()
    sleep(1)
```

2 - or, as you are using a text file, you can open it as line buffered.
See the documentation on [open](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open) for more details.
You need `buffered=1` for line buffering:

```
from time import sleep

f = open('testfile.txt', 'w', buffering=1)
while True:
    f.write("A, B, C, D, E\n")
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you! How much overhead do these options incur generally? Each iteration (and thus writing to the text file) is about 1 second, and I'm likely going to be running thousands of iterations per dataset that I'm working on. I'm hoping to minimize overhead.